# How to highlight menu?

Tags: magento-1.9

In CMS pages i add one button show in image

[image]

When i m click on that button it redirect to another page that time CMS is not highlighted

[image]

which shown in above image so how to highlight menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your controller action method, copy following code.

```
$this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('cms/page');
$this->renderLayout();
```